# Unity - How to hide Homebar on iOS ( defer system gestures and hide home button )

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, gesture, deferred, home-button

The game is in landscape mode and at the bottom of the screen are some ui buttons, for this reason I would need to hide iPhone home bar and use deferred edges.

1. Using "Hide home button on iPhone X" correctly hides the button, but any single tap will show the bar and single swipe will close the game. Not good.
2. Using deferred system gestures only, behavior is correct, it takes two swipes to close the game. The problem is that the home bar is always visible, its greyed out, but always visible. Gets highlighted on a first swipe, closes game on the second. Thats good, but cant have visible home bar all the time, its right on top of the buttons. Not good.
3. Used deferred edges and Hide home button option is acting like 1), ie deferred edges are ignored for some reason. Not good.

Question: Is there some way to have home bar hidden and appear only on a swipe and on second swipe closes game. Ie functionality like 2) but the bar is hidden instead of greyed out?

Answer (score 2):

In player settings under `Resolution and Presentation` you could check `Render over native ui`

[image: Screen shot]

This option will force unity to display app contents over the native ui, however then you need to setup a custom way to close your application.